# WSO2 Carbon : Change default claim dialect

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm new to using WSO2 (currently unsing v 5.8.0).

I am trying to change the default claim dialect of WSO2 Carbon (http://wso2.org/claims) to a freshly created claim dialect.

When changing the dialect, I would like the "user Profile" to change accordingly.

I've already changed 2 lines in the config file "Identity.xml", but It doesn't seems to do anything :

> AttributesClaimDialect
>
> ConsumerDialectURI

The default User Profile looks like this

[image]

I would like the new one to only use the claims attributed in the new Dialect.

I really hope there is a way to do this, and avoid using the default Claim Dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://wso2.org/claims is the default claim Dialect which is used by the WSO2 server for the user-related operations. This name will be hardcoded in the codebase. So it is not possible to change it.

If you want to change "user Profile". Let's say if you want to show a new claim in the profile, you need to set that particular claim in http://wso2.org/claims as 'Supported by Default.

[image]